# how to destroy activity if I'm in a surfaceView

Tags: java, android

I have two activities. My MainActivity has a button with OnClickListener that starts second activity using

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class));
```

In my second activity I set up some SurfaceView:

```
setContentView(new SecondView(this));
```

From that SecondView class I call other classes and do some tasks. After a certain user input I want to exit/destroy second activity and go back to main activity. I've tried this (found it as answer to someones question):

```
SecondActivity getBack = new SecondActivity();
getBack.finish();
```

but it does not work -> app has stopped.

My question is: how to stop/exit activity In this kind of situation? Or should I approach this some other way?

Regards, Coding_for_fun

(As before, if I find a solution on my own I'll paste it here so others can use it.)

**EDITED**

Ok, this is what I have in LogCat(don't know what you need):

```
04-27 15:18:42.107: I/ActivityManager(383): Displayed com.example.nova/.MainActivity: +1s834ms
04-27 15:19:21.287: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.287: W/AudioService(383): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.297: I/ActivityManager(383): START u0 {cmp=com.example.nova/.GameActivity} from pid 3101
04-27 15:19:21.317: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.317: W/AudioService(383): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.317: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.317: W/AudioService(383): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: W/AudioService(383): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: W/AudioService(383): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: W/AudioService(383): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: W/AudioService(383): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: W/AudioService(383): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: W/AudioService(383): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: E/SoundPool(383): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.327: W/AudioService(383): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
04-27 15:19:21.337: W/AudioService(383): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
04-27 15:19:21.677: D/LightsService(383): Excessive delay setting light: 447ms
04-27 15:19:21.727: D/LightsService(383): Excessive delay setting light: 53ms
04-27 15:19:21.907: W/EGL_emulation(3101): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-27 15:19:22.217: I/Choreographer(3101): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-27 15:19:22.407: D/(3101): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8491668, tid 3117
04-27 15:19:22.807: I/ActivityManager(383): Displayed com.example.nova/.GameActivity: +1s426ms
04-27 15:19:24.397: D/dalvikvm(3101): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 309K, 12% free 2962K/3360K, paused 45ms, total 47ms
04-27 15:19:26.617: D/dalvikvm(3101): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 433K, 17% free 2962K/3552K, paused 35ms, total 41ms
04-27 15:19:26.917: W/EGL_emulation(3101): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-27 15:19:37.907: W/ActivityManager(383): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{b4165e70 u0 com.example.nova/.GameActivity t41 f}
04-27 15:20:52.987: D/ConnectivityService(383): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
04-27 15:20:53.077: D/ConnectivityService(383): Done.
04-27 15:20:53.077: D/ConnectivityService(383): Setting timer for 720seconds
04-27 15:20:53.267: D/MobileDataStateTracker(383): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
04-27 15:20:53.317: V/BackupManagerService(383): Running a backup pass
04-27 15:20:53.327: V/BackupManagerService(383): clearing pending backups
04-27 15:20:53.327: V/PerformBackupTask(383): Beginning backup of 7 targets
04-27 15:20:53.357: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(521): Dictionary info: dictionary = UserHistoryDictionary.en_US.dic ; version = ? ; date = 1398626453
04-27 15:20:53.357: I/PerformBackupTask(383): Initializing (wiping) backup state and transport storage
04-27 15:20:53.377: D/BackupManagerService(383): Now staging backup of android
04-27 15:20:53.397: D/BackupManagerService(383): Now staging backup of com.android.providers.settings
04-27 15:20:53.407: D/BackupManagerService(383): Now staging backup of com.android.providers.userdictionary
04-27 15:20:53.407: D/BackupManagerService(383): Now staging backup of com.android.dialer
04-27 15:20:53.417: D/BackupManagerService(383): Now staging backup of com.android.sharedstoragebackup
04-27 15:20:53.427: D/BackupManagerService(383): Now staging backup of com.android.browser
04-27 15:20:53.427: D/BackupManagerService(383): Now staging backup of com.android.calendar
04-27 15:20:53.437: V/LocalTransport(383): wiping all data
04-27 15:20:53.467: D/PerformBackupTask(383): invokeAgentForBackup on @pm@
04-27 15:20:53.467: E/PerformBackupTask(383): Error invoking for backup on @pm@
04-27 15:20:53.487: I/PerformBackupTask(383): Backup pass finished.
04-27 15:20:53.487: E/PerformBackupTask(383): Duplicate finish
```

Now my app goes back to MainActivity but but just freeze there.

Comment: Anyway, your approach is wrong if you create an instance of SecondActivity it's not related to any activity in Android so it makes no sense to finish it. To finish the activity from SecondView use the instance you pass to it when you create the view and call finish on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong, you create a new class and call `finish` to it. But this class is not related to any Activity in Android so the application will crash.

To fix it, you should use the instance which you pass to it when you create it

```
setContentView(new SecondView(this));
```

You should edit your `SecondView` class to save it.

So create a field

```
private Activity activity;
```

and in your constructor

```
activity = (Activity)context;
```

Then, when you want to destroy the activity

```
activity.finish();
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Marco. I'm very sorry but it turns out that this was not the reason why my app crashes (I just started this android adventure of mine so I don't quite get it yet). I have class that extends thread (does some graphics for me) and I can't finish my activity because of it. I'll try to figure this one on my own for a while and if I don't succeed I'll post another question. thx again.

Comment: This answer helped you to fix your problem or not? Anyway, if you post the Logcat we can help you. Your problem is caused maybe because you try to update UI from another thread.

Comment: Your answer was helpful in a way(learned something new) but my app still won't work. I edited my question by adding LogCat results like you asked.

Comment: I've managed to resolve my problem. It was not related to my question (sorry about that) so I will not paste it here. Thanks again for your help Marco, your answer is helpful for this question.